# Rendering array of object object data in array.map() in react

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem where I'm trying to render data. I've tried looping over an array of objects with `.map`, but it's returning `[object Object]` rather than the HTML element that was mapped to.

[You can see a photo of my console output of `result` here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfLQy.jpg).

```
const AdminSidebar = () => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {result.map((repos) => (
        <tr className="alert" >
          <td className="product-item-name">{repos.name}</td>
          <td className="product-item-email">{repos.email}</td>
          <td className="product-item-phone">{repos.contact}</td>
          <td className="product-item-code">{repos.clubregistrationnumber}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  )
};

export default AdminSidebar;
```

Comment: You should include a key to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. In your case it should be something like `<tr className="alert" key={repos.id}>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const AdminSidebar = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <tbody>
        {result.map((repos,index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            {
              repos.map((items, itemsIndex) => {
                if (typeof items !== 'object') {
                  return <React.Fragment key={`${index}-${itemsIndex}`}/>
                  const itemsResult = Object.values(items);

                  return (
                    <React.Fragment key={itemsIndex}>
                      {itemsResult.map((item) => (
                        <tr key={item._id} className="alert">
                          <td className="product-item-name">{item.name}</td>
                          <td className="product-item-email">{item.email}</td>
                          <td className="product-item-phone">{item.contact}</td>
                          <td className="product-item-code">
                            {item.clubregistrationnumber}
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  )
                }
              })
            }
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};

export default AdminSidebar;
```

Comment: @AryanMoradi why does this work? please provide a description with your answer so others can learn from it too